# Fetching elements between a node = XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Original Request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<typ:CustomerResponse xmlns:typ="http://xml.mycomp.com/customer/types">
 <typ:CustomerReturn>
    <typ:Address>
      <typ:state>PA</typ:state>
      <typ:city>Harrisburg</typ:city>
    </typ:Address>
    <typ:User>
       <typ:firstName>test</typ:firstName>
       <typ:lastName>test</typ:lastName>
    </typ:User>
 </typ:CustomerReturn>
</typ:CustomerResponse>
```

I removed xml namespaces using the xslt below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@xsi:nil[.='true']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

After running the above transformation on my orginal xml which has namespaces I get the below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CustomerResponse>
 <CustomerReturn>
    <Address>
      <state>PA</state>
      <city>Harrisburg</city>
    </Address>
    <User>
       <firstName>test</firstName>
       <lastName>test</lastName>
    </User>
 </CustomerReturn>
</CustomerResponse>
```

I want to enhance the existing xslt file to get output similar to below.

Expected Output

```
  <CustomerResponse>
       <Address>
          <state>PA</state>
          <city>Harrisburg</city>
        </Address>
        <User>
           <firstName>test</firstName>
           <lastName>test</lastName>
        </User>
 </CustomerResponse>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please show the original input XML and the expected output of the transformation.

Comment: Hi Michael , added the expected output.

Comment: Please show us the original input, too. --  Are you aware that the output you want is not well-formed XML?

Comment: Hi Michael , updated both the original request and expected one. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:typ="http://xml.mycomp.com/customer/types"
exclude-result-prefixes="typ">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="typ:CustomerReturn">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks works awesome. Thank you very much.  Is it possible to explain what is being done?

Comment: The first template creates a corresponding element in no-namespace for every element in the original XML. It does so recursively, traversing the entire tree from root  to leaves. The second template overrides for `typ:CustomerReturn`: it continues the recursion (by calling `<xsl:apply-templates/>`), but it skips creating a corresponding element for the current node. Thus children of `typ:CustomerReturn` move up in the hierarchy and become children of `CustomerResponse`. -- See also: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#section-Processing-Model

Comment: Thanks a lot , Michael!